# Is Web Crypto Api able to read certificates in external devices(smart cards and tokens) and sign a xml?

Tags: javascript, php, web, cryptography

I´m developing a web application that needs to sign xml files, but before this need to read a certificate plugged in usb port( smart cards, tokens).

Is the Web Crypto Api and javascript able to do this? If this is possible, how can i do this?